# wordpress wp_editor() does not support <style> tag

Tags: plugin-development

when using wp_editor() it creates a tinymce editor. when I adding html content to the editor, it automatically add `<br>` and `<p>` tag to `<style>` tag properties. and the styles do not affect the html elements.
how I can add `<style>` support to it?
Thank you

Comment: what are you doing that requires this? `wp_editor` isn't intended as an arbitrary HTML entry point, and there are better tools to insert CSS inline, such as the customizer, the advanced panel in the block editor, HTML widgets, or dedicated components such as the codemirror library used for editing themes and plugins

Comment: @TomJNowell I want to add an editor to my plugin. It is used to create simple email template. but adding <style> to text editor is my problem. is there any way to add another editor to my plugin?